# How to Properly Escape Quotes in WMI Query

Tags: c++, windows-7, automation, wmi, wql

I have the following WMI Query, which polls whetehr a file has been created in `C:\test` :

```
Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 
Where TargetInstance Isa "Cim_DirectoryContainsFile" 
and TargetInstance.GroupComponent="Win32_Directory.Name='C:\\test'"
```

I am able to run this in `wbemtest.exe` without any issue - here is the output from wbemtest :

[image]

However, when I try running `mofcomp myfile.mof` in CMD, I am getting a "unparsable query" error. In the .mof file, my query looks like this:

```
"Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 "
"Where TargetInstance Isa \"Cim_DirectoryContainsFile\" "
"and TargetInstance.GroupComponent=\"Win32_Directory.Name=\"C:\\\\test\"\"";
```

And I really can't figure out what is wrong with my character escaping... 
I know that in WQL I don't need to concatenate the strings, so I don't think that is the issue. However, I have no idea whether I need to use single or double quotes, or whether a single quote inside a set of doubles needs to be escaped, or whether double-quotes are usable within a set of quotes...

The documentation on this detail is pretty much non-existent, so would really appreciate it if anyone with any experience could help me out!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This filter can be written like this:

```
"Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 "
"Where TargetInstance Isa \"Cim_DirectoryContainsFile\" "
"and TargetInstance.GroupComponent=\"Win32_Directory.Name=\'C:\\\\test\'\"";
```

and this works without issue. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886755/mofcomp-subscription-not-working-and-saved-file-acting-strange) for more details on what happened here. It seems to be that some kind of issue with `Notepad++` interferes with this formatting.

Also notice the use of single and double quotes in the filter string.